# What is $\frac{d}{dx}x^i$?

Tags: complex-numbers

What is $\frac{d}{dx}x^i$ where $i=\sqrt{-1}$? Does the proof as for real indices apply in the same way here?

Comment: The question needs some clarification. 1) What is your definition of $x^i$? 2) Is $x$ considered to be real (positive)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rule does apply, so the derivative is $ix^{i-1}$.

For a simple proof,

$\dfrac{d}{dx}x^i$

$=\dfrac{d}{dx}e^{i\ln x}$

$=e^{i\ln x}\dfrac{d}{dx}i\ln x$

$= e^{i\ln x}\cdot\dfrac{i}{x}$

$ =i\dfrac{e^{i\ln x}}{e^{\ln x}} $

$=ie^{(i-1)\ln x}=ix^{i-1}$

Comment: Which proof are you thinking of which goes through for complex exponents?

Comment: Right, so the same proof does *not* go through. This is not the usual proof for real exponents.

Comment: This should probably include some statement on the choice of branch.

Comment: @Kevin Carlson, I admit I didn't initially interpret "does the proof apply" (usually it's rules that apply) as "is the proof valid"... edited now.

Answer (score 1):

$i$ is just treated as a constant, so the power rule applies.